# Sobrepor links acima da mascara fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, css3

Tenho que fazer um efeitou onde o usuário entra e clica no link para **acender a luz** e quando sair **apagar a luz**. O único problema por enquanto é que a mascará fica na tela normalmente mas os links para clicar e acender a luz e apagar parece que fica em baixo e não da para clicar. Tentei usar o `z-index` mas não adiantou. O meu código:

**HTML e CSS**

```css
.icones-topo{
    margin-left:6px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:99999;
}

.icones-topo a{
    color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.mascara{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.80;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mascara"></div>

<li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
    <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile">
    <?php echo $this->conta_model->user('nome', 'first_name');?> </span>
    </a>

    <div class="icones-topo">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="botao"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('usuario/configuracoes');?>"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    </div>

</li>
```

Comment: Amigo se puder  inserir o código dentro do local específico onde tem os sinais de "<" e ">" fica bem mais fácil de ajudar...

Comment: @Alisson, teria como adicionar um snippet, assim ficaria mais fácil simular o problema e propor uma solução

Comment: O ideal é que os elementos que você precisa clicar para apagar e acender a luz, também tenham o posicionamento absoluto.